# How to order (using an specific method) a .txt file using Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to order a .txt file that looks like this:

```
G1-G2-H2-I2
E1-E2-E3
D5-E5-F5
F8-F7
J4-K4
D8-D9
B9
H4
L13
C12
FIN
```

The order I'm trying to obtain is A1>A2>B2 ... and so on, so I'm trying to order it alphabetically and if they have the same letter then I want them to be ordered numerically. In the example I posted you can see that everything is correctly ordered instead of the line that contains:

```
F8-F7
```

When it should be:

```
F7-F8
```

I want to provide another example with more rearrengements to do, if the first line of the .txt file is:

```
H2-G2-I2-G1
```

It should be changed to:

```
G1-G2-H2-I2
```

After making all of this changes I want to create a new .txt file that contains the correct order and follows the same structure.

So I managed to order the lines that only contain two pairs by transforming them into numbers (using ASCII) but I'm really stuck on how to order the other lines.

The .txt file will always have the same structure, this means that:

1st line → 4 pairs
2nd line → 3 pairs
3rd line → 3 pairs
4th line → 2 pairs
5th line → 2 pairs
6th line → 2 pairs
7th line → 1 pair
8th line → 1 pair
9th line → 1 pair
10th line → 1 pair
11th line → Always contain 'FIN' string

I'm trying to do this with Matlab, I have the latest version installed.

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering can be easily done using `sort`, the following code reads the input file, sorts each line and writes it to the output file:

```
function [] = sort_file(input_file_name, output_file_name)

input = fopen(input_file_name, 'r');
output = fopen(output_file_name, 'w');

delimiter = '-';
for k=1:10
    line = fgetl(input);
    split_line = strsplit(line,delimiter);
    % add leading zeros to ensure correct sorting
    split_line = regexprep(split_line, '^([A-Z])([0-9])$', '$10$2');
    sorted_line = sort(split_line);
    % remove leading zeros before writing the output
    sorted_line = regexprep(sorted_line, '^([A-Z])0([1-9])$', '$1$2');
    fprintf(output, '%s\n', strjoin(sorted_line,delimiter));
end

fwrite(output, 'FIN');

fclose(input);
fclose(output);

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this won't work if I put this J9-K9-K10-L10, it gets ordered this way: J9-K10-K9-L10 but it should be: J9-K9-K10-L10

Comment: @LunarParks: I updatede my answer, it now works for these cases as well

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [the natsort toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34464-customizable-natural-order-sort) that does exactly what you want.

From its documentation:

```
A = {'a2', 'a', 'a10', 'a1'}; 
sort(A) 
ans = {'a', 'a1', 'a10', 'a2'} 
natsort(A) 
ans = {'a', 'a1', 'a2', 'a10'}
```

On your example:

```
>> natsort(strsplit('J9-K9-K10-L10', '-'))

ans = 

'J9'    'K9'    'K10'    'L10'

>>
```